# How do I remove white background for select option in Chrome?

Tags: css

Here an example http://jsfiddle.net/h6PLV/ `background:none;`

On Google Chrome have white color around the select option. In Firefox looks great.

How do I remove the white color on Chrome browser?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add -webkit-appearance: none;

```
.inputtxt {
    border:0;
    background:none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

​**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h6PLV/1/)** example

Comment: Possible to keep the drop down icon?

Comment: when I resize the window for the fiddle so that the Result pane is narrower than the select the dropdown arrow portion becomes detached from the rest of the select.  Not sure if there's a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this is what you want, but try :

```
 -webkit-appearance:none;
```

Comment: Thanks Yavanosta. BTW `-webkit-appearance:none` will remove the drop down icon.

Answer (score 1):

You need to detect the browser using jQuery

```
if($.browser.chrome){
userAgent = userAgent.substring(userAgent.indexOf('chrome/') +7);
userAgent = userAgent.substring(0,userAgent.indexOf('.'));  
version = userAgent;
  // If it is chrome then jQuery thinks it's safari so we have to tell it it isn't
$.browser.safari = false;
         }
```

Then you can apply multiple changes to these in your css such as background:none by specifying if it's chrome or not.

```
background-color:#ffffff;
background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0,               #f4f4f4), color-stop(0.48, #eeeeee), color-stop(0.5, #f6f6f6), color-stop(0.8, #ffffff));
background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(center bottom, #f4f4f4 0%, #eeeeee 48%, #f6f6f6 50%, #ffffff 80%);
background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, #f4f4f4 0%, #eeeeee 48%, #f6f6f6 50%, #ffffff 80%);
background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #f4f4f4 0%, #eeeeee 48%, #f6f6f6 50%, #ffffff 80%);
background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #f4f4f4 0%, #eeeeee 48%, #f6f6f6 50%, #ffffff 80%);
background-image:linear-gradient(top, #f4f4f4 0%, #eeeeee 48%, #f6f6f6 50%, #ffffff 80%);
```